# join tables from multiple mysql host

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables in different databases in different mysql hosts. can i write a single SQL statement to implement the inner join operation？

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP-Mysql table join from different host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582621/php-mysql-table-join-from-different-host)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join tables from two different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your MySQL version, you might be be able to use [Federated Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html). Refer to [Accessing Distributed Data with the Federated Storage Engine](http://mysql.lamphost.net/tech-resources/articles/mysql-federated-storage.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

That would mean connecting to another MySQL host from INSIDE the SQL statement. To my knowledge, this is not possible and I would regard it as highly dangerous if it were.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to join two tables from different hosts. You can store the result from one of the tables in a hash keyed on the join attribute, and then perform the join operation in your program.

Answer (score -4):

it is not possible to connect to two databases in same query

Comment: to two database it is possible: `SELECT db1.tb1.* FROM db1.tb1 LEFT JOIN db2.tb1 ON db1.tb1.field1 = db2.tb1.field1`.  The question here was more about hosts than databases

Comment: Pretty strange that there are a lot of other answers that claim that this **is** possible