# Joining tables across multiple servers

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I guess we can do `database1.table1 join database2.table2 on` etc. I.e. join tables in separate databases on the same server.
Is it possible to join tables across different sql servers?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/mysql-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases

Comment: It is possible with multiple connections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join tables from two different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server)

Answer (score 3):

you can use [FEDERATED Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html).

```
 The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote
 MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology.
 Querying a local FEDERATED table   automatically pulls the data
 from the remote (federated) tables.  No data is stored on the local tables.
```

[The site shows a good illustration](http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/mysql-federated-table/)