# how can I inner join 2 mysql tables on 2 different mysql server

Tags: mysql, linked-server

I am trying to inner join 2 tables located on 2 different MySQL Servers.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT id, name FROM server2.db1.account AS new_data
INERT INTO server1.db2.account(id, name) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = new_data.name
```

In SQL Server there is link server future which allows you to do this but I am not sure how this is done using MySQL Server.

Note: I need to be able to inner join all the tables from one server to another.

I am looking for a solution where I don't have to do every table separately as I have multiple servers and many tables on each database.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: This is a frequently question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11114197/926639

Answer (score 0):

Go read about the federated engine. It is the MySQL version of linked servers. You will be able to query a remote table like a local table using the federated engine. Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) link.