# MySQL-Oracle bridge connection

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, bridge

I wonder if anyone Please help me with ideas to build a **bridge connection between MySQL to Oracle 11g** Database connection. For instance, I have MySQL and Oracle Databsae installed in my pc. Is it possible to retrieve Data from Oracle Database in MySQL? Any suggestion/feedback will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Don't know if it's quite what you are looking for as it is MySQL to MySQL but does this help you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server

Comment: Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Perl module, DBIx::MyServer, that makes it possible to use other databases such as Oracle from MySQL, see http://web.archive.org/web/20141113060908/http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/dbixmyserver.html. It acts as a proxy that speaks MySQL. Unfortunately it seems a bit dead, the link refers to an archive rather than the live site, but perhaps depending on your requirements you can use it anyway?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definetely give a try.