# Is there a way to join table from api call in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

Is there a way to join table from api call (different server)? 
In my table I store ID of center and centers table is on different server. Now I need a query to join centers table and to select only center name from there. 
If that is not a possible what is the alternatives?

Comment: Can you show us some code so we get a better idea how the current situation is? Also a bit more context of your project would be great. There is an excellent entry about [**How to ask a question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO.

Comment: sorry if my question was not clear. I have a table beneficiaries where I store center_id and that ID came from different server (my apps communicate with laravel passport). Now on index page I need to show center name and I need something like `join(table from different server, 'beneficiaries.center_id', '=', table from different server.id)`

Answer (score 1):

You can join tables of different databases and even if they are on different servers.
You have to use [Mysql Federated Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

You have to create a federated table based on the table at another remote location to use the way you want. The structure of the table have to be exactly same.
The idea goes like this:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE example_table (
        id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
        ...
    )
    ENGINE=FEDERATED
    CONNECTION='mysql://remoteuser@remote_host:[port]/federated/example_table';
```

Then You can simply join using laravel's join function:

```php
...
join('example_table', 'other.center_id', '=', 'example_table.id')
...
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Check [join-tables-from-two-different-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server) for joining from remote server.

Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/join-between-tables-in-two-different-databases) to join tables from different databases

If you cannot do the above:

You can use a custom logic within Laravel, to pull the data from the different sources, and then combine it to something useful for you via PHP