# How to join Multiple databases from different hosts in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there any way to use join query with Multiple databases from different servers?

my `database.php` is

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            ...
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '192.233.****.*'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'db2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
         ...
        ]
```

and i need to implement it in join query.

My controller function is

```
public function function1(){
$db1 = DB::connection('mysql2');
$result = TABLE1::join($db1 . '.' . 'table2', 'table2.id','=','table1.table2_id');

return Datatables::of($result);

}
```

Comment: possible duplication.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel

Comment: Its differ from that, In mentioned question, they are using the same host.

Comment: same logic applies.
https://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: Yeah i have tried those logic. But cant able to use in Join.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join tables from two different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cant paginate them correctly.

To be able to use server side pagination, the data need to be from the same source and implement pagination.

The only solution you might have to be able to show a dataTable of the results with proper pagination is to get all the data (order them with the collection) and paginate in the JS using datatable.

Another solution would be to have two table with conventional server side pagination.

The most complicated solution and the best one (without using replication) is to use [Federated Storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) where it is like having a table that represents the one in the second database. That way you communicate with only one database and it handles the second one by itself.